# How to calculate probability of something occurring AT LEAST $n$ times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a group of $10$ people, I know that the probability of $5$ being boys is $${^{10}C_{5}\over{2^{10}}}$$ But how do you calculate the probability of **AT LEAST** $5$ being boys? Would you add up the probabilities of having $5-10$ boys, like shown below?

$${^{10}C_{5}\over{2^{10}}} + {^{10}C_{6}\over{2^{10}}} + {^{10}C_{7}\over{2^{10}}}+.....+{^{10}C_{10}\over{2^{10}}}$$

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, if there are five children, then at least 3 boys means 3 boys OR 4 boys OR 5 boys, and since those events are mutually exclusive, the probability of their union is the sum of the probabilities.

Comment: It's $1$ minus the probability of at least $3$ girls.  If boys and girls are equally likely, then it's $1$ minus itself, so $\frac12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a fine way to do it.  This particular problem has a nice symmetry to it.  You are asking for a majority of boys.  All the other cases have a majority of girls.  As boys and girls are equally probable, the answer is $0.5$.

Comment: Cool, I didn't even notice that. Thanks :)